# Select Multiple Not Posting Values

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having problem with ASP.NET MVC not recognizing select multiple items.  I'm rendering the following multi select:

```
<select name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Items[index].GroupIDS)" class="group-id" multiple="multiple">
   @if (entity.Groups != null)
   {
      foreach (var grp in entity.Groups)
      {
         <option value="@grp.ID" selected="selected">@grp.Description</option>
      }
   }
</select>
```

I can't use Html.ListBoxFor because my setup is a little more complicated.  It renders as the following right before postback:

```
<select name="Items[0].GroupIDS" class="group-id init" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="3" selected="">Item 1</option>
      <option value="4" selected="">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to post back to a property in a collection, defined as the following (on the model):

```
   //ViewModel
     //Items collection - that object has a property of:
        public long[] GroupIDS { get; set; }
```

When the POST happens, the following is what the Request.Forms collection is returning.  When more than one item is selected, nothing is coming back at all (below is the Request.Forms.AllKeys collection):

```
[23]: "Items[0].ID"
[24]: "Items[0].GroupIDS" -- Only 1 item returned; [1] and [2] have more than 1
[25]: "Items[0].IsDeleted"
[26]: "Items[1].ID"
[27]: "Items[1].IsDeleted"
[28]: "Items[2].ID"
[29]: "Items[2].IsDeleted"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You dont need  <option value="@grp.ID" selected="selected"> ... it is enough just to write  <option value="@grp.ID" selected>

Comment: @MikNiller I did have it that way; as I was troubleshooting it was a random test I took and I never reverted it back.

Comment: it's still the wrong way to do it ... you have html helpers that make the entire dropdown code, as you are writing `selected` in every single option, and you should not

Comment: @balexandre I'm oversimplifying and using a jquery plugin; this is the underlying representation though (bootstrap tagsinput plugin).  I don't agree this is the wrong way to do it.  I'm writing data attributes to the option elements and MVC doesn't give you that.

Comment: override the helper and create your own, makes all much cleaner and simplyfied ...

Answer (score 1):

The modelbinder cannot bind to arrays. You need an `IList` property, such as:

```
public List<long> GroupIDS { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried that to no avail.  Either way, as soon as more than 1 item are selected, it produces the following form output, with no GroupIDS reference:
    [23]: "Items[0].ID"
    [24]: "Items[0].IsDeleted"